# iOS App linking or Connecting 2 iOS Apps or iOS App Integration

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have my home App which has few buttons serving different features and one of the feature is “X” and this feature “X” is developed by another vendor (in Xcode) now when I tap the X Button in my App. I should be able to open the App that is developed by the other vendor.

How do I implement this scenario?

Fyi: user should be downloading only one App but should be able to access both the Apps

Comment: You haven't asked a question, nor do you appear to have done even a bare minimum of research on your issue before posting.

Comment: my apology, I was checking if the above scenario is possible?